# Datepicker not working on collection of items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datepicker

The scripts in my layout:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').each(function() {
            $(this).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
        $('#datePicker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

In a view in my application, I get to return a list of items which includes this model:

```
public partial class COLLECTION DETAIL
{
    (...)
    public System.DateTime DATE_ADDED { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DATE_EXPIRE { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

And this model gets rendered like this

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.COLLECTION.Count; i++)
{
    <div>
        Added: @Model.COLLECTION[i].DATE_ADDED.ToShortDateString()
    </div>
    <div>
        Expire: 
        <input type="text" id="datePicker" value="@Model.COLLECTION[i].DATE_EXPIRE.ToShortDateString()"/>
    </div>
}
```

The datepicker works fine for the first item of the collection, but not for the others because of the ID. And if I use a class instead, the datepicker now does not work. Can anyone help me make the whole thing work out? I need to be able to set a new date (as shown) and then post the data in a `POST` method.

Comment: Change the ID to class.

Comment: Change the HTML to a class, then just do what you're doing but make sure the case is correct.

Comment: Tried to change the ID to a class, but that does not work.

Comment: And did you make sure the case is correct, when using classes, case matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your JavaScript. There's no need to loop (`.each()..`) since the datepicker is already applied to the array of elements selected.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
          changeMonth: true,
          changeYear: true
});
```

Change the ID to a class in the HTML. Check the casing:

```
<div>
    Expire: 
    <input type="text" class="datepicker" value="@Model.COLLECTION[i].DATE_EXPIRE.ToShortDateString()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Aaaaarg! Tried this about 10 times before posting, but hey, now it works :) Will mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, here is the [DEMO and JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4XjHq/)

```
$(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true
            });
        });
```